# Get WinHTTP to use the credentials from WinInet

Tags: c++, c, winapi, credentials, winhttp

I'm writing a service, hence using WinHTTP instead of WinInet. While reading MSDN it talks about setting `WINHTTP_OPTION_USE_GLOBAL_SERVER_CREDENTIALS` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384066(v=vs.85).aspx) to have WinHTTP get credentials handed down from WinInet.

Now I am testing my service, and running it under a user context and am trying to have it authenticate to a proxy using basic authentication. Since I don't have prior knowledge of the user credentials I want them handed down from WinInet. I am calling [`WinHttpSetCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384112.aspx) with `NULL` values for user and password and am having no success.

```
bResults = WinHttpSetCredentials( hRequest, 
                                  dwTarget, 
                                  dwSelectedScheme,
                                  NULL,
                                  NULL,
                                  NULL );
```

I am also setting the registry key
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ShareCredsWithWinHttp to a DWORD value of 1

and calling

```
BOOL bSetValue = TRUE;      
if(!WinHttpSetOption(hSession,WINHTTP_OPTION_USE_GLOBAL_SERVER_CREDENTIALS,
                     &bSetValue,sizeof(bSetValue))){

    printf("Setting options failed\n");
}else{
    printf("Settings options success\n");
}
```

The above code seems to return just fine.

I can't seem to find many examples of WinHttp using default passwords or getting them from WinInet. Does anyone have any experience with this or somewhere they can point me? Thanks.